# Regarding Inclinometer Functions

Tags: flutter

**https://github.com/huffSamuel/off-road-inclinometer/ **
we had only this one flutter library for inclinometer and there you can see in below file that its only supported to <3.0.0 flutter version and we have latest

File path : https://github.com/huffSamuel/off-road-inclinometer/blob/main/src/pubspec.yaml

So anyone have any Flutter Library or SDK which can support in Flutter version 3.7.4 ?

We integrated this inclinometer Functions in Flutter 3.7.4 but as of now its deperecated - it will not be possible in latest version so please guide over there.

Comment: One of the things you can do is to fork the existing repository and make the necessary changes to be compatible with the latest Flutter version.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you can use this  https://pub.dev/packages/sensors_plus to achieve what you need but,If you didn't succeed the flutter plugin to get the inclinometer to use the native plugin inside the native kotlin code and access it using the flutter [Check the Documentation](https://docs.flutter.dev/development/platform-integration/platform-channels)

Comment: Hi,

we used the same method as Gyroscope concepts and getting o/p like this
please check screenshot : https://prnt.sc/bqz4GAXI1VkJ

Now i want to convert these degrees into an Inclinometer view like this : https://prnt.sc/YB69ZhvJEnUJ

so any suggestion or any calculations for it ?